# pandas df.fillna() not replacing na values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this **(For clarity: This represents a df with 5 rows and 8 columns)**:

```
            BTC-USD_close  BTC-USD_volume  LTC-USD_close  LTC-USD_volume  \
time                                                                       
1528968660    6489.549805        0.587100      96.580002        9.647200   
1528968720    6487.379883        7.706374      96.660004      314.387024   
1528968780    6479.410156        3.088252      96.570000       77.129799   
1528968840    6479.410156        1.404100      96.500000        7.216067   
1528968900    6479.979980        0.753000      96.389999      524.539978  

            BCH-USD_close  BCH-USD_volume  ETH-USD_close  ETH-USD_volume  
time                                                                      
1528968660     871.719971        5.675361            NaN             NaN  
1528968720     870.859985       26.856577      486.01001       26.019083  
1528968780     870.099976        1.124300      486.00000        8.449400  
1528968840     870.789978        1.749862      485.75000       26.994646  
1528968900     870.000000        1.680500      486.00000       77.355759
```

And I would like to replace the nan-values in the ETH-USD_close and ETH-USD_volume column. However, when i call `df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`, nothing seems to happen; the missing values are still there and nothing changes in the columns when I step through the program with a debugger.

When i use `df.isna()` to check whether my nan values are correctly interpreted by pandas, this does seem to be the case; check the output of the first few rows when I check by `print(df.isna())`:

```
            BTC-USD_close  BTC-USD_volume  LTC-USD_close  LTC-USD_volume  \
time                                                                       
1528968660          False           False          False           False   
1528968720          False           False          False           False   
1528968780          False           False          False           False   
1528968840          False           False          False           False   
1528968900          False           False          False           False  

            BCH-USD_close  BCH-USD_volume  ETH-USD_close  ETH-USD_volume  
time                                                                      
1528968660          False           False           True            True  
1528968720          False           False          False           False  
1528968780          False           False          False           False  
1528968840          False           False          False           False  
1528968900          False           False          False           False
```

A call like `df.dropna(inplace=True)` *does* remove the entire row, but this is not what I want. Any suggestions?

EDIT: In case anyone wants to reproduce the problem, one can download the data from https://pythonprogramming.net/static/downloads/machine-learning-data/crypto_data.zip, unzip it and run the following code in the same directory:

```
import pandas as pd

#Initialize empty df
main_df = pd.DataFrame()

ratios = ["BTC-USD", "LTC-USD", "BCH-USD", "ETH-USD"]
for ratio in ratios:
    #SET CORRECT PATH HERE
    dataset = f'crypto_data/{ratio}.csv'
    #Use f-strings so we know which close/volume is which
    df_ratio = pd.read_csv(dataset, names=['time', 'low', 'high', 'open', f"{ratio}_close", f"{ratio}_volume"])
    #Set time as index so we can join them on this shared time
    df_ratio.set_index("time", inplace=True)

    #ignore the other columns besides price and volume
    df_ratio = df_ratio[[f"{ratio}_close", f"{ratio}_volume"]]

    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df_ratio
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df_ratio)


main_df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True) #THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK
```

Comment: Can you share some info about your dataframe, e.g. `df.describe()` and `df.info()`? Or even some dummy data? Also, please don't post screenshots like that, it is not useful. Rather copy-paste the output of `print(df)` or some excerpt from a csv file.

Comment: `df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace='True')` works for me.

Comment: That is so strange. I could edit steps to reproduce the problem into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah.

You cannot `ffill` a `NaN` value if it is the first value of a series: it has no previous value.

Using `.ffill().bfill()` could solve this but might be creating false data.

Comment: Which consists of a collection of series (columns).

Comment: Thanks for helping =) Appreciate it. I'll just use bfill. 

Just so I can actually learn something from this; pandas dataframe consists of series (columns) and an operation as fillna() is applied column-wise? 

And ffill propagates last valid observation forward to next (Which is why my code didn't work as there is no "valid last"), whereas bfill uses the next valid observation to fill the gap? Leaves me wondering what to do if first and last observation of a series is missing lol

Comment: Yes indeed a dataframe applies its functions column-wise by default. Note that `.bfill()` stands for *backfill*, which is forward fill but then from the other direction. In a time series dataset such as yours this can create false data since you are taking data 'from the future' and filling the previous time unit with it.

Comment: What's your strategy for replacing missings in a time series dataset?

Comment: I'd use `ffill`only  and then `dropna` if necessary.